# Date in NSString format returning null iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

Iam getting date in NSString format " 2016-03-16T00:00:00.000+05:30 "
Iam using following method to convert NSString date into proper NSDate format and it returning null.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-03-16T00:00:00.000+05:30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

//dateFromString returns null.
```

Pls help

i have updated with this code

```
    NSString *strDateFor = [polygon valueForKey:@"effective_from"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateformate dateFromString:strDateFor];
    NSLog(@"date : %@",date); //null
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"The strDate is - %@", strDate); //null
```

again null

Comment: how should i correct this  ???

Comment: Compare the string and the format. They don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the line:

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

doesn't make any sense because you're not using the `NSDate` instance you're creating here. Just leave it out.

Secondly, *always* set the date formatter's `locale` if you parse a date string like this. By default, `NSDateFormatter` uses the user's current locale, which could be anything, so you can't rely on it. You probably want the `en_US_POSIX` locale since it's guaranteed to not change in the future.

Thirdly, your date format string is wrong because you didn't specify the fractional seconds (`.SSS`).

This works:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-03-16T00:00:00.000+05:30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: yes ,its working. if i want only date part what should i do?